# Escape ~ in SED when I match all chars

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I'm trying to replace a string in a CSV terminated by ~ that it's like a password and I want to escape the delimiter to stop.

I use:

```
sed -i "s/\(z.*\~\)/\"\1\"/g"
```

And it's okey but the `~` is not escaped and the regex goes to the final of the line.

Is some way to "stop" the match any character that stops with `~`

These are examples of that I have. The second part it's correct because I want to double quote the subexpresion:

```
zTG*?KM)ии*v=?~~~~~
zTG*?KMии$FhB?~S~~~~
```

I want to have (or stop)

```
"zTG*?KM)ии*v=?"~~~~~
"zTG*?KMии$FhB?"~S~~~~
```

but with de word command at the top I have:

```
"zTG*?KM)ии*v=?~~~~~"
"zTG*?KMии$FhB?~S~~~~"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo 'zTG*?KM)ии*v=?~~~~~' | sed -En 's|([^~]+)|"\0"|p'
```

Result: `"zTG*?KM)ии*v=?"~~~~~`
It works for me.

Comment: Note that `\0` only works with _GNU_ `sed`; per POSIX (and with BSD `sed`) you must use `&`.

Comment: Sorry to answer a bit late, I try your sentence and works for me too, but I had used the Sundeep sentence before and it works too. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 4):

```
$ cat ip.csv 
zTG*?KM)ии*v=?~~~~~
zTG*?KMии$FhB?~S~~~~

$ sed -i 's/z[^~]*/"&"/g' ip.csv 
$ cat ip.csv
"zTG*?KM)ии*v=?"~~~~~
"zTG*?KMии$FhB?"~S~~~~
```

- `z[^~]*` the character `z` followed by zero or more non `~` characters. Since `*` is greedy quantifier, it will try to match as many as possible
- `"&"` add quotes around matched pattern
- Note: the `g` modifier is not needed if there is only single match in a line

Answer (score 1):

@Oriol, Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk '{sub(/~/,s1"&");sub(/^/,s1);print}' s1="\""  Input_file
```

Comment: That works, but `awk '{sub(/~/,"\"&"); print "\"" $0}' Input_file` is probably simpler.

Comment: Sorry to answer a bit late, I try this sentence and read the documentation about awk (because I use only sed or egrep) but finally I use Sundeep answer because yours didn't work for me, but thanks anyway.